# Display all total sum for current date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I did displaying total sum of task_time for every department but at this moment it shows all values I want to show sum only where date = current date.

For example I want to show only sum of values where date in "array" = March 2017. I don't care about days.

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="ngrepeatSelect">
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <p>
    Current date: {{currTime  | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
    </p>
        <md-table-container>
            <table md-table>
                <thead md-head>
                    <tr md-row>
                        <th md-column>Dept</th>
                        <th md-column>Total time</th>
                        <th md-column></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody md-body>
                    <tr ng-if="!data.model" md-row md-select="test" md-on-select="" md-auto-select ng-repeat="test in tests">
                        <td md-cell>{{ test.dept }}</td>
                        <td md-cell>{{ test.total }}</td>
                        <td md-cell></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </md-table-container>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('ngrepeatSelect', ['ngMaterial'])
    .controller('ExampleController', function($scope, $filter) {
    var data = [{
            id: "1",
            user: "John Doe",
            dept: "test",
            date: "2017-03-02",
            task_time: "83"
        }, {
            id: "2",
            user: "Mark Doe",
            dept: "test",
            date: "2017-02-02",
            task_time: "41"
        }, {
            id: "3",
            user: "Zac Doe",
            dept: "other",
            date: "2017-02-04",
            task_time: "12"
        }, {
            id: "4",
            user: "Zac Doe",
            dept: "test",
            date: "2017-03-02",
            task_time: "41"
        }, {
            id: "5",
            user: "Zac Doe",
            dept: "test",
            date: "2017-03-02",
            task_time: "41"
        },{
            id: "6",
            user: "Zac Doe",
            dept: "test2",
            date: "2017-03-02",
            task_time: "41"
        },{
            id: "7",
            user: "John Doe",
            dept: "test",
            date: "2017-01-02",
            task_time: "41"
        },{
            id: "8",
            user: "Zac Doe",
            dept: "test",
            date: "2017-01-01",
            task_time: "41"
        },{
            id: "9",
            user: "John Doe",
            dept: "tests",
            date: "2017-02-12",
            task_time: "41"
        }, {
            id: "10",
            user: "Zac Doe",
            dept: "test2",
            date: "2017-02-13",
            task_time: "53"
        }];
        $scope.currTime = new Date();
             var totalPerDept = [];
        angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
            var index = findWithAttr(totalPerDept, 'dept', item.dept);

            if (index < 0) {
                totalPerDept.push({
                    dept: item.dept,
                    total: parseFloat(item.task_time)
                });
            } else {
                totalPerDept[index].total += parseFloat(item.task_time);
            }
        });
        $scope.tests = totalPerDept;

        function findWithAttr(array, attr, value) {
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
                if (array[i][attr] === value) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

    });
```

I've created [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrp3qxgq/71/) to show what I am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done without using Moment.js. Just need to use Date object methods.

```
angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
        var index = findWithAttr(totalPerDept, 'dept', item.dept);

        if (index < 0) {
            totalPerDept.push({
                dept: item.dept,
                total: checkDate(item) ? parseFloat(item.task_time) : 0
            });
        } else {
                if(checkDate(item)) {
                totalPerDept[index].total += parseFloat(item.task_time);
            }
        }
    });
    $scope.tests = totalPerDept;

    function checkDate(item) {
        var date = new Date(item.date);
      var currDate = new Date();
      return (currDate.getMonth() === date.getMonth() && currDate.getYear() === date.getYear() );
    }
```

Comment: super cool it also works. Can you check m ycomment under machinehead115 answer? (This issue is also with ur function)

Comment: I think you forgot to divide the first condition by 60. Moreover, if you want to get time in hours and minutes, you can divide the total time of each dept. by 60 for hours and remainder on dividing by 60 for minutes then their combination would give you the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Moment.js and use the `isSame` function to check if the months and years match. I updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrp3qxgq/72/) to use Moment.

```
angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
  var index = findWithAttr(totalPerDept, 'dept', item.dept);

  if (index < 0) {
    totalPerDept.push({
      dept: item.dept,
      total: checkDate(item.date) ? parseFloat(item.task_time) : 0
    });
  } else {
    if (checkDate(item.date)) {
      totalPerDept[index].total += parseFloat(item.task_time);
    }
  }
});

$scope.tests = totalPerDept;

function checkDate(date) {
  return moment().isSame(date, 'month');
}
```

Comment: Thank you is great solution but I have one more problem. I've updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mrp3qxgq/73/ I want to divide total sum by 60 to get time in hrs and minutes but it divides only first value?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vks9009/d1b8z52q/).

Script

```
angular.module('ngrepeatSelect', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('ExampleController', function ($scope, $filter) {
  var data = [{
      id: "1",
      user: "John Doe",
      dept: "test",
      date: "2017-03-02",
      task_time: "83"
  }, {
      id: "2",
      user: "Mark Doe",
      dept: "test",
      date: "2017-02-02",
      task_time: "41"
  }, {
      id: "3",
      user: "Zac Doe",
      dept: "other",
      date: "2017-02-04",
      task_time: "12"
  }, {
      id: "4",
      user: "Zac Doe",
      dept: "test",
      date: "2017-03-02",
      task_time: "41"
  }, {
      id: "5",
      user: "Zac Doe",
      dept: "test",
      date: "2017-03-02",
      task_time: "41"
  }, {
      id: "6",
      user: "Zac Doe",
      dept: "test2",
      date: "2017-03-02",
      task_time: "41"
  }, {
      id: "7",
      user: "John Doe",
      dept: "test",
      date: "2017-01-02",
      task_time: "41"
  }, {
      id: "8",
      user: "Zac Doe",
      dept: "test",
      date: "2017-01-01",
      task_time: "41"
  }, {
      id: "9",
      user: "John Doe",
      dept: "tests",
      date: "2017-02-12",
      task_time: "41"
  }, {
      id: "10",
      user: "Zac Doe",
      dept: "test2",
      date: "2017-02-13",
      task_time: "53"
  }];
  $scope.currTime = new Date();
  var totalPerDept = [];
  angular.forEach(data, function (item) {
      var index = findWithAttr(totalPerDept, 'dept', item.dept);

      if (index < 0) {
          totalPerDept.push({
              dept: item.dept,
              total: parseFloat(item.task_time)
          });
      } else {
          totalPerDept[index].total += parseFloat(item.task_time);
      }
  });
  $scope.tests = totalPerDept;

  function findWithAttr(array, attr, value) {
      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
          if (array[i][attr] === value) {
              return i;
          }
      }
      return -1;
  }

  $scope.getTotalTime = function (dept) {
      var totalTime = 0;
      angular.forEach(data, function (item) {
          if (item.dept == dept && item.date.indexOf($scope.currTime.format('YYYY-MM')) > -1)
              totalTime += parseInt(item.task_time, 10);
      });
      return totalTime;
  }

  $scope.getMonth = function (date) {
      return date.format('MMMM YYYY');
  }

});

    (function () {
        var D = "Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday".split(","),
            M = "January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December".split(",");
        Date.prototype.format = function (format) {
            var me = this;
            return format.replace(/a|A|Z|S(SS)?|ss?|mm?|HH?|hh?|D{1,4}|M{1,4}|YY(YY)?|'([^']|'')*'/g, function (str) {
                var c1 = str.charAt(0),
                    ret = str.charAt(0) == "'"
                    ? (c1 = 0) || str.slice(1, -1).replace(/''/g, "'")
                    : str == "a"
                      ? (me.getHours() < 12 ? "am" : "pm")
                      : str == "A"
                        ? (me.getHours() < 12 ? "AM" : "PM")
                        : str == "Z"
                          ? (("+" + -me.getTimezoneOffset() / 60).replace(/^\D?(\D)/, "$1").replace(/^(.)(.)$/, "$10$2") + "00")
                          : c1 == "S"
                            ? me.getMilliseconds()
                            : c1 == "s"
                              ? me.getSeconds()
                              : c1 == "H"
                                ? me.getHours()
                                : c1 == "h"
                                  ? (me.getHours() % 12) || 12
                                  : (c1 == "D" && str.length > 2)
                                    ? D[me.getDay()].slice(0, str.length > 3 ? 9 : 3)
                                    : c1 == "D"
                                      ? me.getDate()
                                      : (c1 == "M" && str.length > 2)
                                        ? M[me.getMonth()].slice(0, str.length > 3 ? 9 : 3)
                                        : c1 == "m"
                                          ? me.getMinutes()
                                          : c1 == "M"
                                            ? me.getMonth() + 1
                                            : ("" + me.getFullYear()).slice(-str.length);
                return c1 && str.length < 4 && ("" + ret).length < str.length
                  ? ("00" + ret).slice(-str.length)
                  : ret;
            });
        };
    })();
```

HTML

```
<body ng-app="ngrepeatSelect">
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <p>
        Current date: {{currTime  | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
    </p>
    <md-table-container>
        <table md-table>
            <thead md-head>
                <tr md-row>
                    <th colspan="3">{{getMonth(currTime)}}</th>
                </tr>
                <tr md-row>
                    <th md-column>Dept</th>
                    <th md-column>Total time</th>
                    <th md-column></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody md-body>
                <tr ng-if="!data.model" md-row md-select="test" md-on-select="" md-auto-select ng-repeat="test in tests">
                    <td md-cell>{{ test.dept }}</td>
                    <td md-cell>{{ getTotalTime(test.dept) }}</td>
                    <td md-cell></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </md-table-container>
</div>
```